# CSS Div inline-block content overlay

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

please help me fix the css div content overlay problem
at http://tinyurl.com/n2stvj6
the Related blog post Div., is overlapping post_content Div.

i need the same layout in above url without content overlapping.

```
<div class="post_content">

      <div class="related-blog-posts">
      related content
     </div>

   <p> content goes here </p>

</div>

Css:
.post_content {
    position:relative;
}
.related-category-posts {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    right: 0;
    /* display: inline-block; */
    /* overflow: hidden; */
    background: #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
    width:230px;
}
```

Comment: This is essentially answered here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915831/text-wrapping-around-an-absolute-positioned-div

Comment: Thanks for the ref :) but here @user574632 gave a simple solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use floats:

```
.post_content {
    overflow:hidden
}
.related-category-posts {
    float:right;
    background: #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
    width:230px;
}
```