# Get text in CSS3 column?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I'm using CSS3's support for columns support in a project (so far I've found it much more robust and dependable than most JavaScript solutions out there).

> **Question:** Is it possible to get the text that is in a specific column, in any way?

Comment: Seems not quite ready for prime time: http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn

Comment: Maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9430124/how-to-get-content-of-a-specific-css-column

Comment: @DreamEater: How is jQuery related to this question?

Comment: @DreamEater Because CSS3's support is usually more reliable/faster in my test  cases.

Comment: @Diodeus I'm using it for Mobile Safari, which has had it for awhile.

Comment: @Bergi jQuery is always related.

Comment: @imkost: Good link and even a possible duplicate, only it has no valid answer yet :-(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

And...what, two months later? I finally found the answer to this question. It's reliant on [document.caretRangeFromPoint (Webkit) or document.caretPositionFromPoint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.caretPositionFromPoint).

```
var getAllTextInColumn = function(rect){
    /*
        rect should be the size and x,y of the column
        { top, left, width, height }
    */

    if(document.caretRangeFromPoint){
        var caretRangeStart = document.caretRangeFromPoint(rect.left, rect.top);
        var caretRangeEnd = document.caretRangeFromPoint(rect.left+rect.width-1, rect.top+rect.height-1);
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    if(caretRangeStart == null || caretRangeEnd == null) return null;

    var range = document.createRange();
    range.setStart(caretRangeStart.startContainer, caretRangeStart.startOffset);
    range.setEnd(caretRangeEnd.endContainer, caretRangeEnd.endOffset);

    return range.toString();
};
```

Comment: And that column has to be on-screen, I think range is relative to viewport

Comment: You can make an iframe off the screen and use this code and then the column doesn't have to be on-screen

Comment: @MichaelBates I'm not saying it doesn't (I'm sure it does), just not sure how many use-cases that would fit into.

Comment: @mattsven this is really nice, but how do i get `rect` of a column?

Comment: You're going to have to calculate that from whatever element is being split into columns. Try [`element.getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) for starters.

Comment: Works perfectly except when you have multiple elements that have been split across columns. A table, flex boxes, floats with text between them, etc.

Answer (score 1):

My only guess is to start replacing spaces with a `SPAN`, then detecting when the vertical position of that SPAN gets smaller, then you know you're in the next column. This last SPAN becomes a column marker.

You can then copy the text that is between the beginning/end and/or a column maker.

Comment: Interesting idea. How would you suggest doing that?

Comment: I'd use jquery. Replace the spaces with <span class='marker'> </span>, then use jQuery's .each to loop through the, set, looking at the offsetTop of each element.

Comment: I had a similar idea, but I'm looking for the fastest way to do it. My  method here <span>s all words (jQuery, haha). https://gist.github.com/matt-curtis/5189032

Comment: It spans words, though, because it's not immediately apparent to me on how to get the two space nodes. I guess adjacent text nodes?

Comment: I think narrowing the selector to the element wrapping the text in question would be a bit faster than the entire body. Also, replacing spaces as a string and reinserting the whole thing back into the DOM in one go is WAY faster than maipulating the DOM in every loop. DOM manipulations are SLOW. (forget the nodes, treat it as a blob of text until you start reading the positions of the elements)

Comment: I should mention that $body isn't actually apart of the DOM when I manipulate it - it's an HTML string actualized by jQuery.

Comment: Without tags you cannot identify the position of an element. I think you're on the right track though.

Comment: I mean my content HTML string might include <img>s, or <a>s, and I want to avoid those.

Comment: Ah, I get it. A REGEX could ensure you're outside of < > brackets.

Comment: True, but I haven't found any fail-safe ones, and there's the repeated warning of "don't parse html with regex..."