# How to extract the currently visible text only from a UIWebView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiwebview

I am loading a `XHTML` file in a `uiwebview` and paginating its content by dividing its content in columns by using "-webkit-column" property.
I need to find out the currently visible text on a `uiwebview` not the entire one( the entire text can be easily found by using "document.body.innerText" property)

I tried using "`elementFromPoint`" to find the currently visible text but its not working.

Can anybody help in finding out this.

Comment: Answered this over here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15481764/get-text-in-css3-column/16910555#16910555