# jquery get text of visible column in CSS multicolumn

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I use CSS Multicolumn to show a html file, width of column set to width of window, so only one column shown at a time `_windowWidth = $( window ).innerWidth();` . the height of column also set to hight of window `_windowHeight = $( window ).innerHeight();` . and in the css the overflow of *container* is hidden `overflow: hidden`.

and i can change the visible column with `$('#content').css({"-webkit-transform":"translate(" + (-1 * _column * (_windowWidth + _columnGap)) + "px,0px)"});`

what i want is to **get the current visible column text**.

`$('#content').children(":visible").text();` return all column text.

the nearest question and answer i found is :[Get text in CSS3 column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15481764/get-text-in-css3-column) , he suggest this function:

```
var getAllTextInColumn = function(rect){
    /*
        rect should be the size and x,y of the column
        { top, left, width, height }
    */

    if(document.caretRangeFromPoint){
        var caretRangeStart = document.caretRangeFromPoint(rect.left, rect.top);
        var caretRangeEnd = document.caretRangeFromPoint(rect.left+rect.width-1, rect.top+rect.height-1);
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    if(caretRangeStart == null || caretRangeEnd == null) return null;

    var range = document.createRange();
    range.setStart(caretRangeStart.startContainer, caretRangeStart.startOffset);
    range.setEnd(caretRangeEnd.endContainer, caretRangeEnd.endOffset);

    return range.toString();
};
```

but i dont't know how to get `rect` of a column (eg. column 3)

any help would be appreciated.

tnx in advance.

**UPDATE:**

this function really works but i can't figure out it's parameter, if i pass `left = 0 , top = 0 , width = _windowWidth , height = _windowHeight` it gives me text of first column.

if i pass `left = _column * (_windowWidth + _columnGap) , top = 0 , width = _windowWidth , height = _windowHeight` and _column is **0** or **1** it gives text of first column and if _column > 2 the `caretRangeStart` will be `null`.

if i pass `left = 0 , top = 0 , width = _column * (_windowWidth + _columnGap) + _windowWidth , height = _windowHeight` the `caretRangeEnd` will become `null`, so i can't get it working with any combination, may be someone can help me with that.

Answer (score 0):

From your description you are not really hiding or showing your columns. Your are basically changing the x offset.

You should do the opposite way round: Get the x offset and divide it by - (_windowWidth + _columnGap)

To get the text try:

$('#content').children().eq(index).text();

Comment: it gives me the current column number, i want the **text** in cureent column!

Comment: in your edited answer the `index` is not related to **column**, it means paragraph 3 or 4 or so on ..