# Making a node appear after its siblings using CSS

Tags: html, css

Given makup that looks like this:

```
<div>
    <span> a </span>
    <span class="oddOneOut"> [XYZ] </span>
    <span> b </span>
    <span> c </span>
</div>
```

Is there a way to, using just CSS, force the [XYZ] node to always appear as the last item, on the bottom right, like in the following examples?

```
+--------------+
| a b c  [XYZ] |
+--------------+

+--------------+
| a b c d e f g|
| h i    [XYZ] |
+--------------+
```

---

If there is no straightfoward solution I would also be interested in other ways to achieve the same effect

Comment: Can the XYZ span have a class or ID added to it?

Comment: @ThatMatthew: Of course. All that matters to me is the end result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
div
{
    position: relative; /* make absolute children be absolute inside of it. */
}

div .oddOneOut
{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
    right: 5px;
}
```

The padding may need to be adjusted a bit. The point is to use absolute positioning.

Comment: Is there a way to make is so that the other letters don't go under the `XYZ`? If there are just enough letters to form a line (going up to the "g") the last ones go under the XYZ

Comment: Sorry, I can't think of a fix for that issue that doesn't involve JavaScript. I found this question, which says that this is difficult to do with CSS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499829/css-wrap-text-around-a-bottom-right-div

Comment: Thanks. Somehow just doing the position absolute worked on the *actual* problem I had o_O. Phew.

Answer (score 1):

There *is* a way to achieve this behavior along with all of the positioning stipulations that you wanted in the comments of the accepted answer, all using just CSS.

The solution lies in using the new  [`box-sizing: border-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box-sizing) property to change the way the CSS box model works. With `box-sizing: border-box`, you can use padding as if it were inset spacing.  Therefore, if you specify the `padding-bottom` of the container element to be the `height` of the absolutely-positioned child, the sibling elements will not go underneath the absolutely positioned child.

See [my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brebory/xKSLR/1/) for demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it float including this in the CSS for the second span:

> float:right

Comment: I already tried this and in the second example the XYZ node would  appear on top instead of on the bottom where I want it to be.