# html float bottom

Tags: html, css, css-float

I want to make text float to the very bottom right hand corner of an existing  tag.

I'm still using old school tables (editing existing code). My code is this:

```
<table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
   <tr>
     <td width="50%"></td>
     <td width="50%" valign="top">
       <table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tr>
             <td width="100%" valign="top">KEEP UP TOP</td>
          </tr>
       </table>FLOAT BOTTOM
     </td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

The text that says FLOAT BOTTOM, doesnt obviously. How do make it so that always stays at the very bottom right corner?

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499829/css-wrap-text-around-a-bottom-right-div

Comment: bottom of what? the td? the table?  should it overlap the inner table?  what are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to do this with tables is

- Create a second row
- Give that row (and the cells therein) a fixed height
- Put the text into the right hand column in the second row

One CSS way to do this (without tables) would be

- Give the container you want to place the text in the bottom right corner of `position: relative`
- Wrap the text inside a `<span>`
- Give the span `position: absolute; bottom: 0px; right: 0px`

Answer (score 0):

Use style   `{style="vertical-align:baseline; text-align:right"}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    <table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
   <tr>
     <td width="50%"></td>
     <td width="50%" valign="top">
       <table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tr>
             <td width="100%" valign="top">KEEP UP TOP</td>
          </tr>
       </table><p style="position:absolute; bottom:0px; right:0px;">FLOAT BOTTOM</p>
     </td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: doesnt seem to do it. I think the valign=top is messing things up.

Answer (score 0):

To make it float to the bottom right of the data cell that contains it you could probably do

```
<span style="float:right; vertical-align:text-bottom">FLOAT BOTTOM</span>
```

Comment: For some reason it makes it float underneath the table, not at the base of the cell.