# float:right and relative positioning

Tags: css, image, positioning, css-float

This seems like it should be a simple solution, but I can't seem to figure it out.

I need to position an image in the same spot on every page.  And I need the text to wrap around both the top and bottom of the image.

http://jsfiddle.net/4AnsK/

Notice the space for the image at the top-right?  It doesn't shift down with the image.  I understand why this happens, but I can't figure out how to make it work.

I've tried using relative positioning and setting the "top" value.  I've tried margin-top, padding-top, putting it in an absolute div container, etc.  I can't seem to figure it out.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499829/css-wrap-text-around-a-bottom-right-div

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This seems to work, but it needs a bit of a HTML hack. Basically, you just need to put a zero-width spacer above the image to push it down without affecting anything else.

Add this to the HTML, before the image:

```
<span id="evilNonSemanticSpacer"></span>
```

And use this CSS:

```
#evilNonSemanticSpacer {
    float:right;
    display:block;
    height:210px;
}
img
{
    float: right;
    clear:right;
}​
```

Remove the relative positioning from the image and it is in the right place with the text wrapping around it. The example fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4AnsK/11/).

There is an oddity with Chrome's text wrapping (the line above sits over the image). It doesn't appear in Firefox, though. The only way I can fix it in Chrome is with `margin-top: 1.1em` on the `img`, but that'll also result in white space above the image in Firefox (and possibly other browsers).

Comment: This worked perfectly for me.  I can make do with the margin-top: 1.1em fix.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Feel free to call the span something other than "evilNonSemanticSpacer". I'm just a stickler for semantic markup (everything has and is used for a purpose that is accurate to its definition, e.g. `<a href>` for hyperlinks, `<p>` and not `<div>` for paragraphs) and while it works, adding the `<span>` doesn't quite fit with that. It is structure purely for the purpose of getting something to sit right :)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, could just place the img after the second or third paragraph and remove the `top: 200px`? This will create a similar affect although you can't guarantee it will be exactly 200px. Otherwise you are out of the luck, the paragraphs will float around the original position.

Comment: Thanks, but each page is dynamically driven, so I won't have that kind of control.

Comment: This is a total hack, but could you write some JS to dynamically place it after a given number of elements?