# wrap text around image using layers

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CSS: wrap text around a bottom-right div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499829/css-wrap-text-around-a-bottom-right-div)

Is it possible to have 2 layers, one with text, one an image, and the text wraps around the image?

[image]

Comment: you can do this by `float:right` to the image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

give to the div2 a `float: right`

```
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2">
  </div>
</div>

#div2{float:right;}
```

Comment: http://www.tizag.com/cssT/float.php a tutorial

Answer (score 1):

Need not to add extra div to place image.

**HTML**

```
<div><img src="" />
Content here
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div{width:450px; text-align:justify}
div img{float:right; margin-left:10px}​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Lucnc/2/)**