# How to float a div in the lower right quadrant of another div?

Tags: css

I used the following solution to float a inner-div (corner) to the top right corner of a outer-div (base). That works great.

CSS:

```
#base {width: 100px; height: 100px;}
#corner {float: right; width: 40px; height: 40px; margin: 0 0 15px 15px;}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="base">
    <div id="corner">
        <!--stuff inside corner-->
    </div>
    <!--other stuff inside base-->
</div>
```

Now I want to float the inner-div (corner) to the bottom of the outer base-div (bottom right), but I'm unable to find the correct css configuration. What do I have to change to reach my goal?

It's quite important, that the text of the base div floats the corner-div (as in the example above).

Answer (score 2):

Make the container div `position: relative`.  Then, use `position: absolute` in the div that you want to "float" (but you don't need to use `float`) and set `bottom` and `right` rules to 0.

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/yWGTB/

Comment: I did what you mentioned, but the result is that the content of the base div does not float the corner div. Any Idea?

Comment: See the image below. The text belongs to the base div. Parts of the text are hidden by the corner-div.

Comment: You mean that you want the div to be pushed down by the text content?  In that case you should put the div *after* the text content and then float it.

Comment: Float the base-div containing the text content or the "corner-div"?

Answer (score 2):

try positionning your divs

```
#base {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
        /* positionning */
    position:relative;
}

#corner {
    /* float: right; */ /*floating will be useless */
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 0 0 15px 15px;
        /* positionning */
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
}
```

Now, if you need your outter div content to FLOAT around inner-bottom-corner div, you will have to 'TRICK' your layout, simulating an empty space UNDER the inner-bottom-corner

Further infos :

- [How can I wrap text around a bottom-right div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499829/css-wrap-text-around-a-bottom-right-div) (worth reading )

Comment: I'm sorry, but how can I simulate such an empty space under the inner-bottom-corner-div?

Comment: Follow the link i just posted with answer (worth reading)  :)