# Text wrapping around a div

Tags: css, html, text

How do you get the text to wrap around a `div` if you want the div on the bottom of a container?

I can figure out how to get the text to wrap around the `div` as long as its on top, but if I try and push it to the bottom of the page, the text either doesn't continue across the top of the `div` or the `div` gets pushed in front of the text.

Currently, I have a container `div` and then the darkened box is another div within that div.

I'm trying to create this:

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You just need to work with `float` property.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <img src="http://www.igta5.com/images/trailer-2-gtav-logo.jpg" alt="GTA V" />
    <p>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div img {
    width: 240px;
    float: right;
    padding: 25px;
}
```

[Play with this on jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/9avK4/)

---

### Update

With pure CSS, the most that you will get is manually spacing the sides of image with absolute positioning.

The HTML:

```
<div class="left">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
<div class="right">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
<img src="http://www.igta5.com/images/trailer-2-gtav-logo.jpg" style="width: 240px; height: 140px;">
```

The CSS:

```
img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -125px;
    margin-top: 60px;
}

.left, .right {
    width: 49%;
}

.left {
    float: left;
}
.right  {
    float: right;
}

.left:before, .right:before {
    content: "";
    width: 125px;
    height: 200px;
}

.left:before {
    float: right;
}

.right:before {
    float: left;
}
```

[Play with this on jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/9avK4/7/)

### More information

You can find more information in [this topic, on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499829/css-wrap-text-around-a-bottom-right-div).

Comment: Thats what I currently have. The problem Im having is if I use margin or padding to push the div down to the bottom of the container, the text doesn't wrap across the top because there is still "space" above the div.

Comment: Gg for using the GTA V logo :)

Comment: For those having issues with the original answer... make sure the floating element is first and the wrapping element is straight after. It took me way too much time to figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

`position: absolute;` will get rid of ghost element space