# Wrapping paragraph around div

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

i'm trying to wrap my paragraph's text around the image's div, i've tried everithing but can't figured out why is not working, my head is literally floating left and right by now...

here is the css:

```
/* CSS Document Sidebar */
#sidebar {  
    background-color: #FFF;
    width: 330px;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    }
#news {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 15px;
    position: relative;
    border: solid 1px;
    }
.newsImage {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    bottom: 0px;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: solid 1px;
    }
.newsImage img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    }
#news p.title {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #333;
    margin: 5px;
    }
#news p.content {
    font-size: 12px;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    margin: 5px;
    color: #333;
    }

/* CSS Document Sidebar - END */
```

here the divs

```
  echo '<div id="news">';
  echo '<p class="title">'.$row_Display['PageName'].'</p>';
  echo '<p class="content">'.$row_Display['PageContent'].'</p>';
  echo '<div class="newsImage">';
  echo '<img src="'.trim($row_Display['Image'], '/').'" />';
  echo '</div>';
  echo '</div>';
```

UPDATE:
Add here an example of my structure (i don't have the reputation for upload an image):

```
-----------------------
| <p>[TITLE]          |
|                     |
| <p>[CONTENT]        |
|-----------| content |
| IMAGE div |  wrap   |
|           | around  |
-----------------------
```

SOLUTION:
The problem was the `position:absolute` like Martijn said, but with some tests i manage to reach my own solution. For those who are still stuck on this issue you just need to:

- Delete the `position:absolute` and `position:relative` from the CSS
- Set every paragraph `<p>` to `<div>` with the same classes or id
- Now put in HTML code the `<div 'title'>` on top and set `float:left`
- Create under the previous an emtpy `<div class='clear'></div>` and set the CSS `.clear{clear:both;}`
- Now the image's div goes INTO the content/text's div, make sure to put the `<img src='' />` just before the text so the image can float free.
- And then you can set the CSS with `.img{float:right;}` and `.content/text{float:left;}`. Doing this the text will wrap perfectly around the image

For those who voted negative i'm sry if my previous post wasn't that clear and complete and excuse me for my english.
Hope this can help someone.
Regards.

Comment: Could you please reproduce the issue in a fiddle..

Comment: Provide a fiddle and more information, is impossible to know what do you need

Comment: I update the post, the <p> 'content' keep standing behind the <div class'newsImage'>, but i'm looking for a way to wrap it around the div.

Comment: Until [**CSS Shapes**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-shapes-1/) come on stream...you can't do this with current layout models (AFAIK).

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499829/how-can-i-wrap-text-around-a-bottom-right-div

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid position absolute. This only complicates things in the long run, maintanance-wise.

Then, what you first need to do is create a more table like structure. Create two columns (your title+content and the image) and proceed from there:

```
-----------------------
| [TITLE]    |  IMAGE |
|------------|  IMAGE |
| [CONTENT]  |  IMAGE |
-----------------------
```

The thing you're looking for is `display: inline-block;`, this allows multiple elements to be on one line (`inline`) and still give it dimentions (`block`). This does require the element to touch eachother, no spaces between them (see in the example provided below).

[I've made a simple example for you](http://jsfiddle.net/em97kysL/2/)
*I'm not a float fan. IMO they're always complicating stuff more than they fix.*

Comment: You were right! The problem is the     position:absolute making the div out of the page so the wrap doesn't work, i need to find a way to position the div bottom left without the absolute condition.