# Align floated div to bottom right with CSS

Tags: html, css

I've got a problem that has me stumped.

I want to get the blue div in the top right of the following snippet to align to the bottom right and still have the text wrap around it to the left.

I am able to edit the HTML but I am unable to nest anything inside the `<p>` tag as this is dynamically inserted.

```css
.container{
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
}
.lower-right{
  width: 150px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: blue;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="article">
    <div class="lower-right"> </div>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. </p>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

It seems like it should be simple but I just can't work it out.

Comment: Not that simple but this might be helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/q/32706465/3168107.

Comment: You can't do that *naturally* with CSS. I believe it can be done with a "pusher" element but I'm struggling to find the SO answer so I can link it.

Comment: Thanks for the link but setting it as a background wont work for me as its a button with a hover effect.  I ended up just re-designing it

Comment: It's not set as a background, the div is just not visible to *reveil* part of the background image but it is just as present as in your example. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KdypQb