# CSS GRID content everywhere except last column in first row

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

Let's say there's a scenario where you have a grid with 3 columns and 2 rows, something like this:

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="info"></div>
</div>
```

Elements have these simple styles:

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 400px;
  grid-template-rows: 400px auto;
}

.content {
  grid-column: 1/4;
  grid-row: 1/3;
}

.info {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

This would fill the contents of `.content` element to the whole `.wrapper` available space and the `.info` element would be positioned absolute over in the right top corner.

Is it possible to display the contents of `.content` into everything except to top right cell - like this (red is where the content is):

[image]

Comment: _red is where the content is_ Am I color blind? :)

Comment: @m4n0 I think it's red, but it's definitely more grey than it is red :)

Comment: Wait... I just found out the answer... it's pink! Light red! Hurrah!

Comment: Technically 196 on the RGB scale. So yeah!

Comment: lol, I updated the image

Comment: are you okay with using tow sections for the content (L shaped part)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible using [css grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid).  It would be roughly akin to this [`template-areas`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-areas) syntax:

```css
grid-template-areas: "text square"
                     "text text";
```

Which is returned as invalid ([**demo in codepen**](https://codepen.io/KyleMit/pen/mdQBpEd)):

[image: invalid template-areas]

---

However, this is basically the perfect use case for [**`float`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) which

> places an element on the left or right side of its container, allowing text and inline elements to wrap around it

#### Demo in Stack Snippets & [Codepen](https://codepen.io/KyleMit/pen/yLQzKNy)

```css
.square {
  float: right;
  background: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div>Licks paws hunt anything that moves instead of drinking water from the cat bowl, make sure to steal water from the toilet or grass smells good. Human give me attention meow walk on a keyboard and i dreamt about fish yum! yet gnaw the corn cob chew on cable, eat a plant, kill a hand. Find something else more interesting love me! hopped up on catnip, for taco cat backwards spells taco cat or intently sniff hand, for catto munch salmono. Lick the other cats. Meowwww bite the neighbor's bratty kid bawl</div>
</div>
```

[image: Example of Text Wrap]

---

***Alternatively***, if you want to wrap around text in the *bottom* right, there's a clever solution on [how can I wrap text around a bottom-right div?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67180791/1366033) using [`shape-outside`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/shape-outside)